# Jquery dialog working in IE perfectly but not in FF and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my simple jquery which is working fine in IE but not working in FF and Chrome

```
function publishRedirects() {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure want to publish the redirects?")) {
        callJquery();
    }
}

function callJquery() {
    $('#btnPublish').click(function () {
        $("#dialog").attr('title', 'Publishing').text('Publishing Please Wait').append("<img src='../images/loading11.gif' id='myNewImage' />").dialog({
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $("a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close").remove();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<body> <div id="dialog"></div> <input name="btnPublish" class="button1" type="button" id="btnPublish" value="Publish" onClick="publishRedirects()"> <script type="text/javascript" src="../script/jquery.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="../script/jquery-ui.js"></script> </body>
```

Comment: Could you give us the related html ? A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be perfect :)

Comment: <body>
 <div id="dialog"></div>
 <input name="btnPublish" class="button1" type="button" id="btnPublish" value="Publish" onClick="publishRedirects()">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../script/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../script/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</body>

Comment: Sorry for the levity, but I never in my life thought I would see the words in the title printed on the internet, ever.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are assigning a click event to btnPublish instead of executing the function. if publishRedirects() is called on click of a button and you want the code in callJquery to execute after the user confirms the dialog box, it should look something like this: (notice the removed attach to click event)

```
    function callJquery(){
         var obj= $("#dialog");
         obj.attr('title','Publishing');
         obj.text('Publishing Please Wait');
         obj.append("<img src='../images/loading11.gif' id='myNewImage' />");
         obj.dialog({ 
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                closeOnEscape: false,
                open: function(event, ui) {
                       $("a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close").remove();
                  }
                 });

    }
```

Comment: Hey Thanks!! that worked but now image is not coming in Dialog only in Chrome.It is appearing in IE and FF.any suggestion on that?

Comment: i think it is because of the way you assign the img src. Try using the absolute path instead of relative path

Change: src='../images/loading11.gif'
to : src='/websitename/someFolder/SomeFolder/images/loading11.gif'

Comment: i have edited my answer, try doing like that and then start with only appending the image and check if the images is appended correct. If that fails there is something wrong with your image or css.

Comment: Any idea why this browser compatibility issue is there?I have edited the code as after hiding scroll bar image in dialog is not coming in Fire fox

Comment: I have no idea. try creating a example in http://jsfiddle.net/ it makes it much easier to help you.